# jQuery selector for gt(x) rows for each nested table

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to get at each row **except first and second** for **each** table inside a div.

the html:

```
<div id="ContainerDiv" style="width:100%;display:table">
    <div style="display:table-row">
        <div id="FirstTableDiv" style="display:table-cell">
            <table id="Table1">
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="2">Table 1</th>
                </tr>
                <tr align="right">
                    <th>Column 1</th>
                    <th>Column 2</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <!-- event handler for this and following rows -->
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div id="SecondTableDiv" style="display:table-cell">
            <table id="Table2">
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="2">Table 2</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Column 1</th>
                    <th>Column 2</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <!-- event handler for this and following rows -->
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the jQuery that doesn't work:

```
$('#ContainerDiv > tr:gt(1)').on('dblclick', function () {
    //that's ALL rows of ALL tables, no good
});
```

attempt #2

```
$('#ContainerDiv table tr:gt(1)').on('dblclick', function () {
    //does nothing
});
```

there are several other attempts that all failed. What am I not seeing?

Comment: Failed **how**? Selected the wrong elements? Didn't bind the event handler? Something else didn't work right?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist selected either ALL the rows or none

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#ContainerDiv table tr').not(':nth-child(1),:nth-child(2)')
```

Comment: this works. I don't get how this is any different than `$('#ContainerDiv table tr:gt(1)')` though. Can you explain?

Comment: if you use `$('#Table1 tr:gt(1), #Table2 tr:gt(n)')` jquery selects all elements after the `n` element. it don't know about indexes of every table. But `nth-child(n)` works because it uses 1-based indexing to conform to the CSS specification. http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/#entry-longdesc . Maybe my explanation is not good enough, but my english isn't perfect. I improved code so

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using multiple selectors. It's not elegant, but it works.

```
$('#Table1 tr:gt(1), #Table2 tr:gt(1)').on('dblclick', function () {
    onBoxRowDoubleClick(this);
});
```

If anyone can find a better way to achieve the same: please feel free to add comments or answers.